# mysql get many id's on one row

Tags: php, mysql

How to get all ids separated by comma on one row.

```
id | name

1 | Jonny
2 | Lisa
3 | Ben
```

And with php/mysql get with one query without a loop the ids comma separated. Like "1,2,3"

To be something like this :

```
$query = "SELECT 1,2,3 as oneRowIds FROM tableName";
$result = mysql_query($query);
$result = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
echo $result['oneRowIds'];// and that shows "1,2,3"
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

use `group_concat` function

`GROUP_CONCAT()` function is used to concatenate column values into a single string. It is very useful if you would otherwise perform a lookup of many row and then concatenate them on the client end.

```
select group_concat(id) as oneRowIds FROM tableName
```

Comment: group_concat is going to cut the result (maybe only on command line)

"Warning 1260 Row 218 was cut by GROUP_CONCAT()"